# Can the EVM execute a function over multiple blocks?

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, evm

Is it possible that EVM will execute one function over multiple blocks? I am interested in the case when the contract validates the block.timestamp at the beginning of the function and then use block.timestamp at the end. Can 2nd timestamp differ from the 1st?

Comment: I think it's not. Because every function call will triggered a block and once a blocks reach its memory or allocation the data will continue but assign in other blocks or next blocks

Answer (score 0):

No, execution must happen within one block - though of course if that is not "enough" the execution will instead run out of gas and revert.

Answer (score 0):

Nope It can't. A block is a compilation of transactions that is sent to the Ethereum network and when the block of particular number is validated by validator, only then a transaction passes through. So, since transactions make up block, a transaction can never take gas greater than block gas limit. So, a transaction can never be on multiple blocks as a block is made up of transactions and not vice versa.